# How to load different storyboards depending on the screen of different devices. (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I don't find AutoLayout necessary and I want to Know how to load different storyboards depending on the screen of different devices but in swift 2.
I found most answers in Obj-c and I don't code in Obj-c So to make it clearer, I have multiple storyboards and I want my app to load the right storyboard on the right device.

ex.
iphone5s.storyboard loads on an iphone 5 and iphone 5s

iphone6.storyboard loads on an iphone 6

ipadPro.storyboard loads on and ipad pro

by the way my app is universal

Comment: Why are you fighting the tools? You want one storyboard, not lots. Your whole idea prevents you from supporting multitasking on newer iPads. It makes a lot more work for yourself. It's not scalable. What happens when Apple comes out with some other screen size?

Comment: Please post the answer you found for Objective-C

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy.  AutoLayout is necessary to make your app scalable to future devices.

Comment: @Steve More importantly, it makes your app scalable to current devices.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know how to use Auto layout. I will update my app once when a new screen is added

Comment: if you want your app to be universal then you need to use auto layout, with paging and 1 storyboard. Apple has some great tutorials.

Comment: @J.M I would suggest you learning it instead of trying to find a work around.  There are some great tutorials here under the core concepts heading http://www.raywenderlich.com/category/ios

Comment: Its a good question. I embraced AutoLayout as it uses the same first principals of CAD. But there are some cases where designing for the same screen across iPhone 5 - 6 plus and then iPad to iPad pro simply dumbs down the larger sizes. Why treat the 6plus like an 4s? They must be catered for as of this writing because they are capable of running iOS 9.